# time deference from database value

Tags: php, mysqli

i have these values in database:

---

start_time:

- 1/1/2017 15:38
- 1/1/2017 14:25
- 1/1/2017 13:00

What i want is to calculate the unauthorized duration time against time '16:00:00' and list the duration time. here is what i have done.

```
include 'includes/db_conn.php';
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM time") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
echo "<table border=1>"
. "<tr>"
. "<td>Start Time</td>"
. "<td>Limit</td>"
. "<td>Unauthorized Time</td>"
. "</tr>";
     foreach ($result as $value) {
       $db_date = strtotime($value['start']);
       $limit = strtotime("16:00:00");
       $interval = date_diff($limit,$db_date);
       $unauto = $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
     echo "<tr>"
    . "<td>".$value['start']."</td>"
    . "<td>16:00:00</td>"
     . "<td>".$unauto."</td>".
    "</tr>";
   }
echo '</table>';
```

but this is not working. it shows up with messages like:

> Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,
> integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mct\unauthorized.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mct\unauthorized.php on line 14

please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy way:

```
$db_date = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($value['start'])));
$limit = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime("16:00:00")));
$interval = date_diff($limit,$db_date);
$unauto = $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Mohammad.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $db_date = date_create($value['start']);
 $limit = date_create("16:00:00");
```

alternativly

```
$db_date = strtotime($value['start']);
$limit = strtotime("16:00:00");
$diff = $db_date-$limit;
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($diff.' seconds');
$unauto = $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Comment: the result shows like this - "0:0:2161320" . take the first row value from the database above and try it.